# por que esta conversion a binario me da un valor incorrecto en javascript?

Tags: javascript, algoritmos, revisión-de-código

Tengo el siguiente conversor de números decimales

```js
function binario(numero) { 

  var division = 0; 
  var binario = []; 
  do { 
    division = numero / 2; 
    if (numero % 2 == 0) { 
      binario.unshift("1"); 
    } else { 
      binario.unshift("0"); 
    } 
    numero = Math.round(division); 
  } while (numero > 1); 
  binariof = binario.join(""); 
  alert(binariof); 

} 
binario(28);
```

El problema: me devuelve mal la conversion, en este caso 28 seria 11100 y devuelve 11011.

Que estoy haciendo mal.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes mal tu lógica:

1. Cuando el residuo es 0 en la división, ese es el número que debes agregar a tu arreglo, no 1.
2. Luego debes redondear hacia abajo el entero más cercano después de dividir, no hacia arriba, entonces cambia `round` a `floor`
3. Finalmente debes dividir también por 1, ese número no puedes saltártelo.

Te dejo el Snippet para que lo cheques:

```js
function binario(numero){ 
    var division=0; 
    var binario=[]; 
    
    do { 
        division=numero/2; 
        if (numero%2==0) { 
            binario.unshift("0"); 
        } 
        else { 
            binario.unshift("1"); 
        } 
        numero=Math.floor(division); 
        }
        while(numero >= 1); 
        binariof=binario.join(""); 
        alert(binariof);     
    } 
binario(28);
```

Saludos y suerte

Comment: Excelente, no coloque floor porque me daba bien el resultado y el programa que tengo en mi tablet da error al usar floor. Y el uno habia pensado !=0